# why useSelector return undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

**I can't figure it out why it's returning undefined, when i'm using the useSelector**

In console log it showing Uncaught TypeError: movies.results is undefined

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BECr3.png)[movieLising.js(without render movies)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMHHm.png)
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH81f.png)

> store.js

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import moviesReducer from './movies/movieSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        movies:moviesReducer
    }
})
```

---

> movieSlice.js

Here is the slice where i defined the initial state reducer and actions

```
import {createSlice,createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import movieApi from '../../common/api/movieApi';


const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;


export const fetchAsyncMovies = createAsyncThunk(
    "movies/fetchAsyncMovies",
    async () => {
            const movieTerm ="harry";
            const response = await 
            movieApi.get(`/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${movieTerm}`);
            // console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
    }
);



const initialState = {
    movies:{},
}

const movieSlice = createSlice({
    name:"movies",
    initialState,
    reducers:{

        addMovies:(state,{payload}) =>{
            state.movies= payload;
        }
    },
    extraReducers:{
        [fetchAsyncMovies.pending]: () => {
        console.log("Pending");
        },
        [fetchAsyncMovies.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
        console.log("Fetched Successfully!");
        return { ...state, movies: payload };
        },
        [fetchAsyncMovies.rejected]: () => {
        console.log("Rejected!");
        },
    }
});



export const {addMovies} = movieSlice.actions;

export const getAllMovies = (state) => state.movies.movies;

export default movieSlice.reducer
```

---

> Home.js

This is the Home component where i use the useDispatch

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import MovieListing from '../MovieListing/MovieListing';
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {fetchAsyncMovies} from "../../features/movies/movieSlice"

const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(fetchAsyncMovies());
        
    },[dispatch]);
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="banner-img"></div>
            <MovieListing/>
        </div>
    ) ;
};

export default Home;
```

---

> MovieListing.js(COMPONENT)

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {getAllMovies} from '../../features/movies/movieSlice';
import MovieCard from '../MovieCard/MovieCard';
import './movieListing.scss'

const MovieListing = () => {
    
    const movies = useSelector(getAllMovies);
     let renderMovies ="";
    
     renderMovies = movies.results.length > 0 ? (movies.results.map((movie,index)=>(
         <MovieCard key={index} data={movie} />
     ))) :(
        <div className="movies-error">
             <h3>{movies.Error}</h3>
         </div>
     );
console.log(movies.results);
    return (
        <div className="movie-wrapper">
            <div className="movie-list">
                <h2>Movies</h2>
                <div className="movie-container">
                    {renderMovies }
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default MovieListing;
```

Comment: Its hard to tell what could be the root of that error. Most probably could be that your async fetch is not fullfilled so the movies.results is empty so undefined

Comment: I saw now that you got actually a response

Comment: @CarmineTambascia please have a look at this code  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMHHm.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH81f.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined your initial state as :

`const initialState = { movies:{}, }`

In the very first render, `movies.results` is `undefined`, so trying to use the `length` property leads to an error.

try defining your initial state like this:

```
const initialState = { movies:{results:[]}, }
```

another solution would be always checking if `movies.results` is defined, before using its properties:

```
renderMovies = movies.results && movies.results.length > 0 ? ...
```

Comment: TY sir! It works!